# Code Signing in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having issues validating my app in Xcode 5. I submitted an update 2 weeks ago with Xcode 4 fine. I hadn't touched any of my certificates or provisioning profiles.

When I try to validate, I get:

[image]

When I try to download an identity, Xcode crashes on me.

I went into **prefrence** -> **accounts** and refeshed my Signing Identities and Provision Profiles:

[image]

So I have the identies and profiles. What does it need in the Build Settings under Code Signing nows?

[image]

EDIT:

changed the code signing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. The signing identities under "Release" should really be iOS Distribution, not Developer.  Also true of the AdHoc signing identities.
2. I would check in the keychain to see what signing identities it has.  If you have any expired certificates, delete them.  They can confuse XCode.

EDIT:

On further reflection, it is odd that you have multiple Team Provisioning Profiles, you may want to remove all of those and download them again.

Comment: I do have a bunch of certificates in my keychain. I have a couple with the same names. Should I remove them all and just re-download them?

Comment: I would not remove them if they have not expired, having the same name may be an issue but I do not think so.  See if you can rename them at all.

Comment: Ok, I redownloaded the "iPhone Developer" and "iPhone Distribution" certs and they are in my keychain. I changed the code signing to "iOS Distribution" for both release options. Still have the problem. posted image.

Comment: You should only have one iOS Development and iOS Distribution signing identity (it says you have 3 and 2).  Try exporting both to files - then remove ALL iOS developer/Distribution signing identities using keychain utility, and double-clicking on the files you exported to re-import them into your keychain.  I'm pretty sure that extra count is what is messing you up.  Open Keychain Utility, click on "Keys" and search for "iOS" to see your signing identities.  You should have pairs of public/private keys with some (or all) tied to certificates.

Comment: So I inadvertently deleted the iOS Deve and iOS Dist signing identities in the keychain. I tried to archive for submission and Xcode kept offering to fix the issue. This got me the signing identities back. Now I'm stuck with an issue with a Provisioning Profile.  I believe this fixed this issue and I'll make a new question for the new issue. Thank you.

Comment: Good luck!  Remember that even if you accidentally delete all of your signing stuff, you can always re-create everything starting with a new developer cert... for some people that may be a better way to go than banging your head against mysterious errors.