# Xcode Provisioning Pofile issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I had another issue which I believe got solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186129/code-signing-in-xcode-5).

Now I have an issue with a Provisioning Profile:

[image]

During the previous issue, I deleted the iOS keys in my Keychain. During the archive process, Xcode retrieved them for me, same with the certs.

I created this Provisioning Profile, downloaded, and I have double clicked it to add it, but I keep getting this error when trying to validate.

Any ideas?

If all else, fails, how can I wipe everything clean and start over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the certificate you created became invalid because you deleted the private key. Unless you kept a backup somewhere, you should log in to the development center, delete this certificate, and then create a new one.

Comment: Ok, I do have the .certfSigningRequest that I used to create the the certificate in the dev center. How can I "reinstall" it?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems like its not trusted. I tried just double clicking the file.  I'll have to remove everything and create a new private key and create new profiles, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you deleted the private key it is gone forever. Your developer account only has the public key to keep the private one from being stolen off the servers. The best thing to do when creating provisioning profiles is to save a copy of the private key (you can export from Keychain Access.app) and store them with a copy of your profiles, etc from Xcode. That way if you change machines or add a new machine you can still use the same profiles.